# Slick Grid column not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, grid, slickgrid

[image]See snapshot attached very first time when grid is created it shows like this snapshot, once we change size of any column by dragging or we change displayed column by right click and check/uncheck column to display or hide then column will align properly and also shows data.

one more thing when grid is created and rendered at that time area where this grid render is hidden, i mean there are tab layout and in one of tab these grid is created and active tab is different, does it make any problem.?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid (scroll down for readme)? That is the latest version, the MLeibman branch is quite old. I think this issue may be fixed there.

Answer (score 1):

The grid size is rendered based on the current element size where it is attached to. Thus, if the element is hidden it will not show the correct layout. I usually call {grid}.**resizeCanvas**() when i show the tab. Alternatively, you can show the element while creating the grid and hide it later on.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation i understood the issue
But unfortunately grid.resizeCanvas() is also not working

Comment: Have you tried to check whether you're referencing the correct SlickGrid object and that the tab is shown first before calling resizeCanvas()? I usually get mistaken to call resizeCanvas first before making the tab visible.